# Hide title if there's no data

Tags: javascript

I have have some data that I filter and then I display the data alike so :

```
Object.entries(datas.docs).map(function ([cat, items]){
            %>
      <div class="row" style="padding-left: 15px;margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <h4 class="category"><%=ucfirst(cat)%></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <%
          items.filter(function(item) {
            if (!datas.loggedIn && item.datas.status === 'draft') {
                return false; // skip
            } else if (!datas.loggedIn && item.datas.status === 'private') {
                return false; // skip
            } else if (!datas.loggedIn && item.datas.status === 'disabled') {
                return false; // skip
            }
            return true;
          }).map(function (item) {%> 


        <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6">
          <div class="box_grid wow <%= item.datas.status %>">
            <figure class="block-reveal">
              <div class="block-horizzontal"></div>
              <% if (parseInt(item.datas.language, 10) == 1) { %>
              <a href="#" class="langfr"><i class="flag flag-fr"></i></a>
              <% } else if (parseInt(item.datas.language, 10) ==
              2){ %>
              <a href="#" class="langen"><i class="flag flag-gb"></i></a>
              <% } %>
              <img
                src="http://via.placeholder.com/800x533/ccc/fff/course__list_1.jpg"
                class="img-fluid"
                alt=""
              />
            </figure>
            <div class="wrapper">
              <% if (item.datas.title.length > 31 ) { %>
              <h3><%= item.datas.title.substring(0, 30) %>..</h3>
              <% } else { %>
              <h3><%= item.datas.title %></h3>
              <% } %>
              <p><%= item.datas.shortDesc %></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


      <%});
        %>
      </div>
        <%
        });
```

What I won't it not to show the tilte which is `<h4 class="category"><%=ucfirst(cat)%></h4>` if there's no items to show after the check for the `login` and the `status` but I can't find a solution to do that.

Comment: @Pete — https://ejs.co/

Comment: This is EJS i presume?

Comment: @CamilleSébastienNiessen I'm using EJS in this project